# Getting "Empty Suite" error while running test cases using PyTest in Python (V- 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Below is the code for `conftest.py` & `test_1.py` file. Any idea why am i getting the error "Empty Suite."

1. **conftest.py**

   ```
   import pytest


   @pytest.fixture()
   def setup():
       print("hi")
       yield
       print("end")
   ```
2. **test_1.py**

   ```
   import pytest


   @pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
   class Abc:
       def test_demo(self):
           print("hello")

       def test_demo1(self):
           print("Hey")
   ```

After running `test_1.py` getting below message:

```
Testing started at 15:15 ...
C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe "C:\Program Files\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/famework-pytest/test_1.py
Launching pytest with arguments C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/famework-pytest/test_1.py in C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\famework-pytest

============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\famework-pytest
collecting ... collected 0 items

============================ no tests ran in 0.01s ============================

Process finished with exit code 5

Empty suite
```

Comment: Rename `Abc` to `TestAbc`, see [Conventions for Python test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery)

Comment: Yes, it is working now @hoefling. Is it the new norm in PyTest? Refer to the comment from your trailing link- "test prefixed test functions or methods inside Test prefixed test classes (without an __init__ method)."